# How do I solve this equation $f(x, y) = x - y^3 + y$ local for $h(x)=y$?

Tags: functions

How do I solve this equation $f(x, y) = x - y^3 + y$ local for $h(x)=y$?

$y^3+y=x$

What next?

Comment: What does this mean?